# How to create biomes

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, xna-4.0

I am creating an 2D XNA Tile Based Platformer. I have a tile engine and a world/terrain generator. However, I am trying to create biomes or areas, For example, Desert in one part of the world, ocean on the ends, City in the middle, forests scattered around etc. I can easily make it generate them, but My problem is defining the actual areas to be generated in.

Comment: Maybe if you post your generation code we could help you more...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20551/a-simple-map-four-biomes-and-how-to-distribute-them

Comment: @DampeS8N, My game is a sidescroller. @_Nate Bross, My generator can generate different things by defining an area to generate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random map generation](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/random-map-generation)

Comment: Yes, I know you're doing a side scroller, the same concepts still apply.

Comment: Okay well Ill look over it in a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any specific knowledge of your generation algorithm, I would suggest the following.

Assuming that your world is defined in a multi-dimensional array `Tile[999,99]`

1. Decide how many "biomes" you want and of what type
2. Define the size of each biome
3. Go through your world array, and pick a start point for each biome
4. Update the world array with each biome's tile data

For example:

```
Tile[,] World = new Tile[999,99];
Tile[,] Ocean = new Tile[50,10];
// assume we want the ocean to be top left of the world, flowing off the edge
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        World[i,j] = Ocean[i,j];
    }
}
```

You could, as @Nathan suggested, use a distance from water to define which tile-set to use for each area. This could help keep your maps looking fresh and consistent, yet still be generated on-demand.

Comment: A side scroller makes it even more simple, you just have to decide the start `x` and stop `x` for each biome.

Comment: I actually ended up creating a class to store the end and start of a biome, and an enum on the biome type, But based on your advise

Comment: @Cyral Great! Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

There is a great discussion of procedurally creating random biomes on a map in [Polygonal Map Generation for Games](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) by Amit Patel.  His maps are arbitrary polygonal shapes, not tiles, but the same ideas should be applicable.

Briefly: generate elevation and lakes/rivers on your map using whatever method works for you, then define biomes in terms of elevation and moisture (distance to water).  There is a nice table in the article that suggests different biomes for different combinations of elevation and moisture level.